# WinApi with text files

Tags: c++, winapi, text

I need to copy all files from 1 directory to another, but it's not working.

```
   #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TCHAR buffer[256];
    SetCurrentDirectory ("C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\1");
    GetCurrentDirectory (sizeof (buffer), buffer);
    printf ("%s\n", buffer);
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    HANDLE MyFile;

    MyFile = FindFirstFile ("*", &FindData);
    if (MyFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
    printf ("%s\n", FindData.cFileName);

         CopyFile("C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\1"+FindData.cFileName, "C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\2\\" + FindData.cFileName, FALSE);

      } while (FindNextFile (MyFile, &FindData));
   FindClose (MyFile);
}

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error is 22 C:\Users\Rinat\Desktop\SP\7.cpp invalid operands of types `const char[28]` and `CHAR[260]` to binary `operator+`

Comment: You cannot append char buffers using operator "+". In particular, this will not work: `"C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\1"+FindData.cFileName`.

Comment: Why are you even using `TCHAR` if you're just going to give it to stuff that expects `char`?

Comment: Use `std::string` or `std::wstring`. Whichever it is, give every winapi thing you call wide strings.

Comment: @chris How is `TCHAR` even relevant to this?
@RinatBaiguzhinov see posted answer.

Comment: @bialpio, Well, it wasn't an answer, but it makes no sense at all to use something designed to work for narrow and wide strings if you're just going to assume it's one or the other. Not to mention `TCHAR` is long outdated.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can't add string pointers together like that in C++. You need to use a function (or a class like `std::string`).

```
do {
    char chSrc[MAX_PATH], cdDst[MAX_PATH];
    StringCchCopy(chSrc, MAX_PATH, "C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\1\\");
    StringCchCat(chSrc, MAX_PATH, FindData.cFileName);
    StringCchCopy(chDst, MAX_PATH, "C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\2\\");
    StringCchCat(chDst, MAX_PATH, FindData.cFileName);
    CopyFile(chSrc, chDst, TRUE);
} ...
```

Using `std::string`:

```
do {
    CopyFile((std::string("C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\1\\") + FindData.cFileName)).c_str(),
             (std::string("C:\\Users\\Rinat\\Desktop\\SP\\2\\") + FindData.cFileName)).c_str(),
             TRUE);
} ...
```

Comment: What about `TCHAR`? As far as I know, the above will not work if OP compiles with unicode support.

Comment: @bialpio: The OP is clearly not compiling with unicode support (since all his string literals are ansi) so I figured it made more sense to give him code he can just drop in to play with. As you said above, the Ansi/Unicode issue is really unrelated to his main problem which is misunderstanding how strings work in C++.

Comment: @RinatBaiguzhinov `CopyFile` only copies files. If you want to know how to copy folders, that would be a separate question.